# How to use OneClassClassifier API from Weka in Java project?

Tags: java, weka, data-mining

I need to implement one-class (novelty-detection) classification in java-project.
I have a simple training set with one class:

```
@relation oneclass_test

@attribute class {target}
@attribute text String

@data
target,'mechanical engineering'
target,'engineer'
target,'fuel injected engine'
target,'suspension'
target,'tire-cover'
target,'braking system'
target,'hydraulics'
target,'transmission'
target,'front axle'
target,'spring'
```

I'm using this class to train classifier:

```
public class TestClassifierLearner {
/**
 * Object that stores training data.
 */
Instances trainData;

/**
 * Object that stores the filter
 */
StringToWordVector filter;

/**
 * Object that stores the classifier
 */
FilteredClassifier classifier;

/**
 * This method loads a dataset in ARFF format. If the file does not exist, or
 * it has a wrong format, the attribute trainData is null.
 * @param fileName The name of the file that stores the dataset.
 */
public void loadDataset(String fileName) {
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        ArffLoader.ArffReader arff = new ArffLoader.ArffReader(reader);
        trainData = arff.getData();
        System.out.println("===== Loaded dataset: " + fileName + " =====");
        reader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * This method evaluates the classifier. As recommended by WEKA documentation,
 * the classifier is defined but not trained yet. Evaluation of previously
 * trained classifiers can lead to unexpected results.
 */
public void evaluate() {
    try {
        trainData.setClassIndex(0);
        filter = new StringToWordVector();
        filter.setAttributeIndices("last");
        classifier = new FilteredClassifier();
        classifier.setFilter(filter);

        OneClassClassifier oneClassClassifier = new OneClassClassifier();
        oneClassClassifier.setTargetClassLabel("target");
        classifier.setClassifier(oneClassClassifier);

        Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(trainData);
        eval.crossValidateModel(classifier, trainData, 4, new Random(1));
        System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString());
        System.out.println(eval.toClassDetailsString());
        System.out.println("===== Evaluating on filtered (training) dataset done =====");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * This method trains the classifier on the loaded dataset.
 */
public void learn() {
    try {
        trainData.setClassIndex(0);
        filter = new StringToWordVector();
        classifier = new FilteredClassifier();
        classifier.setFilter(filter);

        OneClassClassifier oneClassClassifier = new OneClassClassifier();
        oneClassClassifier.setTargetClassLabel("target");

        classifier.setClassifier(oneClassClassifier);

        classifier.buildClassifier(trainData);
        System.out.println("===== Training on filtered (training) dataset done =====");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * This method saves the trained model into a file. This is done by
 * simple serialization of the classifier object.
 * @param fileName The name of the file that will store the trained model.
 */
public void saveModel(String fileName) {
    try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) {
        out.writeObject(classifier);
        System.out.println("===== Saved model: " + fileName + " =====");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And part of class for classification:

```
/**
 * This method creates the instance to be classified, from the text that has been read.
 */
public void makeInstance() {
    Attribute textAttr = new Attribute("text", (ArrayList<String>) null);
    ArrayList<Attribute> fvWekaAttributes = new ArrayList<>(1);
    fvWekaAttributes.add(textAttr);

    instances = new Instances("TestInstances", fvWekaAttributes, 1);
    // Set class index
    instances.setClassIndex(0);

    // Create and add the instance
    DenseInstance instance = new DenseInstance(1);
    instance.setValue(textAttr, text);
    instances.add(instance);

    System.out.println("===== Instance created with reference dataset =====");
    System.out.println(instances);
}
/**
 * This method performs the classification of the instance.
 * Output is done at the command-line.
 */
public void classify() {
    try {
        instances.instance(0).setClassMissing();
        double pred = classifier.classifyInstance(instances.instance(0));
        System.out.println("===== Classified instance =====");
        System.out.println("Class predicted: " + instances.classAttribute().value((int) pred));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And finally result of classification:

```
===== Loaded text data: C:\projects\1.txt =====
suspension
===== Loaded model: C:\projects\testData.dat =====

===== Instance created with reference dataset =====
@relation TestInstances
@attribute text string

@data
'suspension'

===== Classified instance =====
Class predicted: *WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*
```

For any text data classifier always return `*WEKA*DUMMY*STRING*FOR*STRING*ATTRIBUTES*` and prediction NaN.
What did I do wrong?

Comment: This is an ill-posed problem. Step back, rethink what you are trying to do. You are trying to emulate a text search via SVM?!?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse It's not a text search. I have a class with documents. And I need to classify other documents: if document belongs to class, program must output 'target' and value of prediction, otherwise 'outlier'.
This data just for examples.

Comment: The way you are using it, it is text search. If that is not what you intended to do, you might be using it wrong... on this data ('hydraulics'), a one-class SVM does not make sense. Because your kernel function is "the text contains 'hydraulics'". In other words, it does text search...

Comment: Ok. I have a set of text documents that belongs to one class (subject).
And I have a single test document. I need to classify this document (target or outlier) and get a prediction (in percentage). Can I do this with one-class SVM or i should have at least 2 classes?
If not, what should I use?

Comment: Are they real text document with lots of shared words, or something like the single-word things you posted above? One-Class-SVMs cannot classify, they can only give you a probability.

Comment: Probability is that i need. I can compare with determinate low-limit and classify manually.
It's a real documents, i can remove stop-words, get a list of words and its initial forms.